# Who is the officer/soldier in a cave that received a morale boost from a spider?

Tags: battle, morals

Today on the radio, I heard about a commander or an officer who was in a cave waiting for a battle to start and he was feeling that he will be defeated because of the large enemy forces (he was in a negative morale). However in that cave he saw a spider trying to build a web, but every time it built it, the wind destroyed it, but the spider didn't give up and he kept trying until he successfully built it, so the commander took the spider as an example that he shouldn't give up and engaged the battle with good morale.

I know there is not enough in my question and I did some google [search](https://www.google.com/search?site=&source=hp&q=commander+defeated+cave+spider+&oq=commander+defeated+cave+spider+&gs_l=psy-ab.3...243.449863.0.450647.69.48.3.0.0.0.664.5473.2-2j6j4j2.14.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..55.13.3971...0j0i10k1j0i13k1j0i5i30k1j0i22i30k1j0i22i10i30k1.9dTrUa0h2dc), [search2](https://www.google.com/search?q=cave+spider+battle+wind+battle&oq=cave+spider+battle+wind+battle&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3584.6375.0.6543.7.6.0.0.0.0.608.608.5-1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..6.1.607...33i160k1.RqGUESaZLnQ), does anyone what is the name of that man? (in the radio he state his named might William but he was not sure). what is the name of the battle ?

Comment: @user2448131 i searched in such way and i had different [results](https://www.google.com.lb/search?site=&source=hp&q=commander+defeated+cave+spider+&oq=commander+defeated+cave+spider+&gs_l=psy-ab.3...243.449863.0.450647.69.48.3.0.0.0.664.5473.2-2j6j4j2.14.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..55.13.3971...0j0i10k1j0i13k1j0i5i30k1j0i22i30k1j0i22i10i30k1.9dTrUa0h2dc)

Comment: Looks like cave spider is a bad search combination if your not playing minecraft.  A lot of answers are found by trying different search terms.

Comment: Would have been (and still is) a good idea to document your preliminary research to avoid the VtC.  What did you search and why weren't the results satisfactory?

Comment: As Mark said, showing what you tried will be better, and may prevent further downvotes.  (now that its edited I can remove mine since you *did* earlier research).

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace google gave me different result. i edit my question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like the legend of [Robert Bruce and the spider](http://www.scotclans.com/scotland/scottish-myths/royal-legends/bruce-spider/).

Bruce was King of Scots and leading the resistance against King Edward I of England. Things weren't going well, and Bruce was on the run during the winter of 1306–07. Supposedly (according to the most common version of the legend) Bruce hid in a cave on [Rathlin Island](https://discovernorthernireland.com/Rathlin-Island-Ballycastle-P8209/) off the north coast of Ireland.

He watched a spider spinning a web. It tried to link from one part of the cave to another. It tried and failed twice, but each time it began again and finally succeeded on the third attempt. Inspired by the spider, Bruce returned to the fray and inflicted a series of defeats on the English, which led to his eventual victory.

The story also supposedly gives us the maxim:

> "If at first you don't succeed, try, try again."